# Getting error while running scoop import job

Tags: mysql, hadoop, sqoop

I'm trying to import data from MySQL database to hdfs using the scoop and I'm getting "No columns to generate for ClassWriter" error.

Here is my scoop command:

```
sqoop import --connect jdbc:mysql://xxxxx.xxxx.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com/xxxx --username xxxx --password xxxx --table xxxx --null-string 'NA' --null-non-string '\\N' --warehouse-dir /user/romeo/finalproject/cardMember
```

Here is the error stack:

> 20/03/08 16:11:27 ERROR manager.SqlManager: Error executing statement:
>   com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException:
>   Communications link failure
>
> The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds
>   ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
>   com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException:
>   Communications link failure
>
> The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds
>   ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
>           at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
>           at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
>           at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411)
>           at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createCommunicationsException(SQLError.java:1121)
>           at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.(MysqlIO.java:357)
>           at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.coreConnect(ConnectionImpl.java:2484)
>           at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:2521)
>           at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:2306)
>           at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.(ConnectionImpl.java:839)
>           at com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection.(JDBC4Connection.java:49)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
>           at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
>           at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411)
>           at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:421)
>           at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:350)
>           at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:571)
>           at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:215)
>           at org.apache.sqoop.manager.SqlManager.makeConnection(SqlManager.java:903)
>           at org.apache.sqoop.manager.GenericJdbcManager.getConnection(GenericJdbcManager.java:52)
>           at org.apache.sqoop.manager.SqlManager.execute(SqlManager.java:762)
>           at org.apache.sqoop.manager.SqlManager.execute(SqlManager.java:785)
>           at org.apache.sqoop.manager.SqlManager.getColumnInfoForRawQuery(SqlManager.java:288)
>           at org.apache.sqoop.manager.SqlManager.getColumnTypesForRawQuery(SqlManager.java:259)
>           at org.apache.sqoop.manager.SqlManager.getColumnTypes(SqlManager.java:245)
>           at org.apache.sqoop.manager.ConnManager.getColumnTypes(ConnManager.java:333)
>           at org.apache.sqoop.orm.ClassWriter.getColumnTypes(ClassWriter.java:1858)
>           at org.apache.sqoop.orm.ClassWriter.generate(ClassWriter.java:1657)
>           at org.apache.sqoop.tool.CodeGenTool.generateORM(CodeGenTool.java:106)
>           at org.apache.sqoop.tool.ImportTool.importTable(ImportTool.java:494)
>           at org.apache.sqoop.tool.ImportTool.run(ImportTool.java:621)
>           at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.run(Sqoop.java:147)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:70)
>           at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runSqoop(Sqoop.java:183)
>           at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runTool(Sqoop.java:234)
>           at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runTool(Sqoop.java:243)
>           at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.main(Sqoop.java:252) Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException:
>   upgradawsrds.cpclxrkdvwmz.us-east1.rds.amazonaws.com
>           at java.net.Inet4AddressImpl.lookupAllHostAddr(Native Method)
>           at java.net.InetAddress$1.lookupAllHostAddr(InetAddress.java:901)
>           at java.net.InetAddress.getAddressesFromNameService(InetAddress.java:1293)
>           at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName0(InetAddress.java:1246)
>           at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1162)
>           at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1098)
>           at com.mysql.jdbc.StandardSocketFactory.connect(StandardSocketFactory.java:249)
>           at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.(MysqlIO.java:307)
>           ... 33 more 20/03/08 16:11:27 ERROR tool.ImportTool: Import failed: java.io.IOException: No columns to generate for ClassWriter
>           at org.apache.sqoop.orm.ClassWriter.generate(ClassWriter.java:1663)
>           at org.apache.sqoop.tool.CodeGenTool.generateORM(CodeGenTool.java:106)
>           at org.apache.sqoop.tool.ImportTool.importTable(ImportTool.java:494)
>           at org.apache.sqoop.tool.ImportTool.run(ImportTool.java:621)
>           at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.run(Sqoop.java:147)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:70)
>           at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runSqoop(Sqoop.java:183)
>           at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runTool(Sqoop.java:234)
>           at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runTool(Sqoop.java:243)
>           at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.main(Sqoop.java:252)

Any idea how to fix this? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Take a look at here -> https://community.cloudera.com/t5/Support-Questions/Sqoop2-ERROR-manager-SqlManager-Error-executing-statement/td-p/31414

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's pretty clear from the stacktrace that this is caused by a **java.net.UnknownHostException** regarding the URI **upgradawsrds.cpclxrkdvwmz.us-east1.rds.amazonaws.com**. The URI is incorrect or the DNS server it points to is not resolving. Update the URI to update the DNS.

Comment: Hi @Jason, Thanks I've updated the URI and post that I'm getting permission issue.

**Diagnostics: Application application_1583656027212_0004 initialization failed (exitCode=255) with output: main : command provided 0
main : run as user is nobody
main : requested yarn user is hdfs
Can't create directory /yarn/nm/usercache/hdfs/appcache/application_1583656027212_0004 - Permission denied
Did not create any app directories**

Any idea how to provide access to this path?